# How to distinguish a link whether it will trigger file downloading or jumping into anywhere else, such as a new URL

Tags: javascript, download, hyperlink, greasemonkey, href

I get an idea writing a GreaseMonkey user JavaScript that can detect which is the exactly real download link rather than an advertisement link or something else.

Actually, I find that some real download link is linked to `.php`. It's tough to detect it I think.

How could I do that, any ideas?

Comment: There is a Firefox add-on that does this. Check out [Link Alert](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/link-alert/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way to do it is to follow the link and check what `Content-type` you will find in the header of the response. If you can, try to send a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET`. That will give you the information you need without actually starting the download.